# Storing a character in a char pointer which was initialized with string

Tags: c++

I tried running the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char *x = "Linux";
    *x = 'T';
    cout<<"value: "<<*x<<endl;
}
```

According to me, it should have stored 'T' in the location pointed to by x. But instead it gave segmentation fault. But when I did:

```
char *x;
*x = 'T';
```

The output was as expected. Can somebody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Using a non-const char pointer to a string literal is deprecated and should not be used in new code. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior. Your second example dereferences an uninitialized pointer which is also undefined behavior. That means it can sometimes **appear** to work.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are `const char*`s, not `char*`s.

Both of your examples are undefined behavior; the second one appearing to work only occurs by accident.